# Amazon Web Services EC2 ssh permission denied (publickey) in Termux

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

`ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@dns` works fine in my laptop running ubuntu. I found out about Termux in android and I wanted to test if I could connect on using the same process and instance. I opened Google Chrome in android and then created a new Key Pair and also added my IP on the security groups. After that I copied it in the home folder created in Termux and modified `chmod 400 androidkey.pem`. When I run `ssh -i androidkey.pem ec2-user@dns` in Termux, it gives me an error saying permission denied (publickey). Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has more to do with Termux and the particular way it does things. I am having the same problem with a different server entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to login through the termux app into ssh client,I would recommend you to check these things

1. make sure the termux app has access to your file system if not run this command `termux-setup-storage`
2. make sure you have the .pem file available in the current location by typing `ls`
3. go to aws console and copy the string to connect to the instance and
   make sure you don't give quotes ("") around the .pem file

e.g enter `ssh -i instancefilename.pem yourinstancepublicdns@amazonaws.com`